# black rectangle on top of soft keyboard when either editexts gain focus

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

[image]

each time i enter the login screen and set focus on either editexts the soft keyboard is shown with a black rectangle on top..i haved tried using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in manifest but with no expecting results..

Comment: Isn't that rectangle used for auto complete/suggestions for words?

Comment: yes...but is there a way to hide it from not showing suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this in your `EditText`

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textUri"
```

Answer (score 2):

finally...the issue was soft keyboard suggestions..i just set the android:inputType property of each of the editexts to "textNoSuggestions" and the black rectangle is not there anymore...

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. For me, nither android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textUri" nor android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" is working.

So is there any more and perfect suggestion to solve the issue?