# Black bar appearing on top of numeric keyboard

Tags: android

I'm having a problem with the keyboard on android, I tested it on a couple of devices and I'm getting the same problem.

I have 3 EditText, the first 2 are of type text and the 3rd is numeric.
The scenario is the following, when the user hits enter it takes him to the next EditText to fill in the info. When the user is at the second EditText the regular keyboard is open, when he hits enter the focus is on the 3rd EditText (Numeric) and the keyboard changes to numeric but the difference of the keyboard sizes(The regular one is bigger than the numeric) produces a black background.

Anybody experienced this type of behavior?

The activity has this in the manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Here's a screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That is probably related to suggestions. You might be able to [fix that by removing suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4488987/503508).

Comment: @Knossos I tried adding no suggestions to all of the EditTexts but still the problem persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried "adjustPan" and "adjustResize" ?? Else i can recommend the Android-API Chapter for Keyboards!! There are several more values specified for adjusting the Keyboard.

---> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: adding adjustResize|adjustPan worked but now the EditTexts are hidden under the keyboard, they no longer scroll to top when focused

Comment: i would try those "state" attributes on the Android-API. Maybe there is one suiting your needs.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33054397/1979882

use this:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textUri"
```

Comment: No luck, I dont think its a suggestions problem since its a black background and not empty suggestion fields

Comment: @MalekHijazi , so, try to grab the viewport of your device in order to understand what is this 'black bar' means.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. For me, nither android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textUri" nor android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" is working.

So is there any more and perfect suggestion to solve the issue?